# How can I compare two enums with OR operator?

Tags: swift, enums, comparison

I need to compare if any of the two cases meets the requirement, I need to take decision else need to do something else. I tried many ways and this is one of them but every way giving error.

```
if case .locked = itemStatus || case .hasHistoryLocked = itemStatus {
    print("YES")        
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but this isn't a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A complete answer would require someone creating an `enum` and a variable. Very few people would be willing to code all of that to provide a good answer. This essentially boils down to a typo and little research on swift. You already have additional conditions in the comments for someone that did take the time.

Answer (score 2):

A `switch` is common pattern for matching a series of cases. See [The Swift Programming Language: Enumerations: Matching Enumeration Values with a Switch Statement](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID147).

E.g.:

```swift
switch itemStatus {
case .locked, .hasHistoryLocked:
    print("YES")
default:
    print("NO")
}
```

---

If you want to add this in an `if` or `guard` statement, you can wrap the above in a computed property. E.g.,

```swift
extension ItemStatus {
    var isLocked: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .locked, .hasHistoryLocked:
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like:

```swift
func doSomethingIfUnlocked() {
    guard !itemStatus.isLocked else {
        return
    }

    // proceed with whatever you wanted if it was unlocked
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can add `Equatable` conformance for this type. So, imagine `ItemStatus` was defined like so:

```swift
enum ItemStatus {
    case locked
    case hasHistoryLocked
    case unlocked(Int)
}
```

Now, if this was your type, you could just add `Equatable` conformance:

```swift
enum ItemStatus: Equatable {
    case locked
    case hasHistoryLocked
    case unlocked(Int)
}
```

If it was not your type and you can not simply edit the original declaration, you could instead add `Equatable` conformance:

```swift
extension ItemStatus: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.locked, .locked), (.hasHistoryLocked, .hasHistoryLocked):                     // obviously, add all cases without associated values here
            return true

        case (.unlocked(let lhsValue), .unlocked(let rhsValue)) where lhsValue == rhsValue:  // again, add similar patterns for all cases with associated values
            return true

        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

However you add `Equatable` conformance to `ItemStatus`, you can then do things like:

```swift
func doSomethingIfUnlocked() {
    guard itemStatus != .locked, itemStatus != .hasHistoryLocked else {
        return
    }

    // proceed with whatever you wanted if it was unlocked
}
```

Comment: I need to compare in guard statement

Comment: Then wrap this `switch` statement in a computed property, and put that in your `guard` statement. Or add `Equatable` conformance.

Answer (score 0):

As your comment I see that you don't want to use `Equatable` to check enum. There is another way to check it using Enum `rawValue`

So it just like you get the rawValue of enum from the key and compare it with your `itemStatus`

```swift
enum Test : Int {
    case locked = 0
    case hasHistoryLocked = 1
    case anything = 2
}

let itemStatus = 0

if itemStatus == Test.locked.rawValue || itemStatus == Test.hasHistoryLocked.rawValue {
    print("Yes")
} else {
    print("No")
}
```

Comment: Operator function '==' requires that 'ItemStatus' conform to 'Equatable'.
It is not allowed in my app to do that.

Comment: Dear @Developer, so instead using ``rawValue`` is the good choice. I just update my answer

Comment: If the enumeration is not `Equatable`, that is frequently because there are cases with associated values. So, having a `rawValue` may not be a viable pattern.